# add view (text view) in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, view, android-asynctask

I used below code for add text view in Async task but :

```
07-26 11:40:39.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26715): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:570)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:596)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2481)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5027)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1840)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1821)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at com.learning.chiazi.MainActivity.addTextView(MainActivity.java:180)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at com.learning.chiazi.MainActivity$Proccess.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:243)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at com.learning.chiazi.MainActivity$Proccess.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-26 11:40:39.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26715):    ... 4 more
07-26 11:40:39.342: E/SemcCheckin(26715): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
```

How can i fixed this?

**Code:**

```
   public void addTextView(int belowId, int id,String text){
        RelativeLayout rSub= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rSub);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, belowId);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId(id);

        tv.setText(text+"\n");
        rSub.addView(tv, lp);

    }

   class Proccess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            addTextView(R.id.tvResult, 1234, "s");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why would you asynctask just to do this `addTextView(R.id.tvResult, 1234, "s");`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run the UI thread in background method like that

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                addTextView(R.id.tvResult, 1234, "s");
        });
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: what should i import?

Comment: No need to import any thing

Answer (score 8):

Use this code , its working for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            TextView tvMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMain);

                tvMain.setText(msg.getData().get("KEY")+"Button Proceed");
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*Button btnDemo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDemo);
        btnDemo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                myAsyncTak();
            }


        });*/

        new AddTask().execute();
    }

    private void myAsyncTak() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TextView textView=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));
                textView.setText("Newly Added TextView");
                View v=View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, null);
                ((RelativeLayout)v).addView(textView);
                setContentView(v);

                Message msg=new Message();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("KEY", "Saurabh");
                msg.setData(bundle);
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                //handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        };

        Thread myThread=new Thread(runnable);
        myThread.start();
    }
    public class AddTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myAsyncTak();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }


}
```

And this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/rlMain" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDemo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMain"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Demo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Erfan13 this code is working for adding textview or any view in asynctask. You can implement this code.

Answer (score 3):

UI works should locate in main thread.

In android AsyncTask.doInBackground(), as its name suggests, ONLY works with background jobs such as networking, db access, etc.

Your method `addTextView()` should locate in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make changes to the GUI in `doInBackground()`
Try this instead so you can make the changes on the UI Thread while still having the code in `doInBackground()`:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
       Runnable run = new Runnable() 
       {
            public void run() 
            {
                addTextView(R.id.tvResult, 1234, "s");
            }
    }; return null;
}
```

Please note, however, that operations that involve changes in the GUI should preferably be located in either `onPostExecute()` or in the `onCreate()`.  That is the best practice, anyway :)

Operations that may take time to be completed, such as running long database queries or other situations where the application may be forced closed should be located in the `doInBackground()`

Comment: For `onPostExecute()` simple right click anywhere in the domain ( { .... } ) of the Activity class, go to Source > Override / Implement Methods, tick `onPostExecute()` and hit OK. (If you are using Eclipse)

Comment: Once you are done with that, place the code for the changes in the TextView inside  the new method.

Comment: Sorry, right click anywhere inside the domain of the AsyncTask class..... I must still be asleep :|

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `TextView` in `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`, because that method operates in backgronud thread and you can't do operations rather than in `UI Thread`, try to add that `TextView` in `onPreExecute()/onPostExecute()` or out of `doInBackground()`

Comment: but i want add it in background!

Comment: why you want to do a UI operation in background ?

Comment: @Erfan13 also just adding a view why do you even need a asynctask for that